# build react app and widget js in one webpack config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, webpack-4

My task is to introduce library to existing create react app based application.

This library need to be build to separate chunk and should not contain any contenthash in name. Ideally should be build to `buildDir/js/widget.js` and that is.

Currently all my `ts` are compiled to `js` during build and are served with `contenthash` in name.
I don't know how to build `widget.js` from `src/widget/index.ts` because entry point is `src/index.ts` and it never catch `src/widget/index.ts` because it is not imported anywhere in main entry point.

This `widget.js` later will be imported in thirdparty web apps via <script> tag and it will be used to initialize some library like `MyLibrary.init(...)` so I think webpack should also have some info so this one `widget.js` should export its methods in special way to the browser during importing external script.

What is best way to get this build proces to work. Also it could be really nice to have it also during development with hot updates.

I don't want contenthash in resulting `buildDir/js/widget.js` because I don't want to ask my customers every time I have new version to update their <script src="..."> for new file name.

Should I eject this CRA? I'm not sure even if I add another entry point that I will be able to control output file name for one entry point as it is and for another without contenthash.

Or maybe it will be better to create separate webpack config (next to unejected CRA) for this widget but then how to run  everything in development mode with hot updates?

I'm using webpack 4.42.0 here in this project.

Answer (score 0):

for your case maybe you need this:

https://dev.to/zhiyueyi/include-your-react-widgets-in-any-web-page-emj

https://github.com/ZhiyueYi/demo-react-web-widget

Comment: This is different use case because this assumes that whole project is build for this widget and in my case I have ReactApp and next to it I need some very small widget that will be using only fraction of full app features and that's why I don't know how to configure webpack so it will build original app as it is and next to it this one additional js file.